# How to do custom error messages in Django Forms

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-forms

I want to make custom error messages for my InstellingenForm, but no matter what I do, I keep getting the browser's standard error messages. The error messages that should be displayed can be seen in choicefield_errors and charfield_errors. Am I missing something cause I feel like it should be working.

I want the error messages to be displayed in red above the concerned input field, right next to the label.

At the bottom of the page, I put a few pictures of how it looks now.

views.py:

```
def instellingenDatabase(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = InstellingenForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            request.session['data'] = request.POST
            spelmodus = request.POST.get('spelmodus')
            if spelmodus == 'woorden':
                return redirect('speelscherm-woorden')
            else:
                return redirect('speelscherm-tijd')
    else:
        form = InstellingenForm()
    return render(request, 'instellingenDatabase.html', {'formulier': form})
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms

SPELMODUS = [
    ('', ''),
    ('tijd', 'Tijd'),
    ('woorden', 'Woorden'),
]

TIJD = [
    ('', ''),
    ('60', '1 minuut'),
    ('120', '2 minuten'),
    ('300', '5 minuten'),
]

WOORDEN = [
    ('', ''),
    ('50', '50 woorden'),
    ('100', '100 woorden'),
    ('150', '150 woorden'),
]

TALEN = [
    ('', ''),
    ('nederlands', 'Nederlands'),
    ('engels', 'Engels'),
]

MOEILIJKHEID = [
    ('', ''),
    ('makkelijk', 'Makkelijk'),
    ('gemiddeld', 'Gemiddeld'),
    ('moeilijk', 'Moeilijk'),
]

charfield_errors = {
    'required': 'Dit veld is verplicht en mag alleen letters bevatten',
    'invalid': 'Dit veld is verplicht'
}

choicefield_errors = {
    'required': 'Dit veld is verplicht',
    'invalid': 'Dit veld is verplicht'
}


class InstellingenForm(forms.Form):
    naam = forms.CharField(label="Naam",
                           max_length=10,
                           required=True,
                           error_messages=charfield_errors,
                           widget=forms.TextInput(
                               attrs={'class': 'input-container'}))

    spelmodus = forms.ChoiceField(label="Spelmodus",
                                  choices=SPELMODUS,
                                  required=True,
                                  error_messages=choicefield_errors,
                                  widget=forms.Select(
                                      attrs={'class': 'input-container', 'id': 'spelmodus', 'onchange': 'hideShow(this.value)', }))

    tijd = forms.ChoiceField(label="",
                             choices=TIJD,
                             required=False,
                             error_messages=choicefield_errors,
                             widget=forms.Select(
                                 attrs={'class': 'input-container', 'id': 'tijdClass'}))

    woorden = forms.ChoiceField(label="",
                                choices=WOORDEN,
                                required=False,
                                error_messages=choicefield_errors,
                                widget=forms.Select(
                                    attrs={'class': 'input-container', 'id': 'woordenClass'}))

    taal = forms.ChoiceField(label="Taal",
                             choices=TALEN,
                             required=True,
                             error_messages=choicefield_errors,
                             widget=forms.Select(
                                 attrs={'class': 'input-container'}))

    moeilijkheid = forms.ChoiceField(label="Moeilijkheid",
                                     choices=MOEILIJKHEID,
                                     required=True,
                                     error_messages=choicefield_errors,
                                     widget=forms.Select(
                                         attrs={'class': 'input-container'}))
```

instellingenDatabase.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'instellingen.css' %}">
    <script type='text/javascript' src="{% static 'instellingen.js' %}"></script>
</head>

<body>
    {% include "header.html" %}
    <div class="bodypage">
        <div class="settings-container">
            <div class="playText">
                Play
            </div>
            <form method="POST" action="">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <label>Naam</label>
                {{formulier.naam}}
                <label>Spelmodus</label>
                {{formulier.spelmodus}}
                <label id='tijdlabel' style="display: none;">Tijd</label>
                {{formulier.tijd}}
                <label id='woordenlabel' style="display: none;">Woorden</label>
                {{formulier.woorden}}
                <label>Taal</label>
                {{formulier.taal}}
                <label>Moeilijkheid</label>
                {{formulier.moeilijkheid}}
                <input type="submit" name="Start" value="Start" class="button">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set `novalidate` to form and skip default browser validations. If you want custom validation in browser before sending form you have to implement it using JS.

You can and should also use backend(in Django on server) validations and then you can show error like this:

```html
{{ formulier.naam.error }}
```

More info how to show backend validation errors is here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually